# Is there a log file of running processes in Server Advantage

Tags: process, audit, advantage-database-server

My name is Josue

I need your help with this:

Is there any way to audit or monitor the server processes that connect to the 
Advantage Database Server?

Is there a log of running processes?

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

There is no existing log of processes that use Advantage Database Server.  Because it is a client/server architecture, there is no mechanism that I am aware of that can easily associate a connection on the server to a specific process.

However, it would be possible to use the system procedure [sp_mgGetConnectedUsers()](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/index.html?master_sp_mggetconnectedusers.htm) to obtain some of this information.  It might be possible to use it to obtain the information you are looking for at a given point in time (a snapshot).

The output of that procedure includes three fields that you might be interested in.  The `Address` column gives the address of the machine that connected to Advantage.  It is typically the IP address of the client application.  But it can also be of the form "IPC Connection N", which indicates that it is using shared memory for communications; this means that the client process is running on the same machine as the server.

The `TSAddress` column might also be of interest.  If the connection is made by a client that is running through terminal services (e.g., a remote desktop), then that column contains the IP address of the client machine.  If you are interested in knowing processes that originate from the server machine itself, then you would need this field to differentiate between those and clients that connected through terminal services.

The other column of potential interest would be `ApplicationID`.  By default, that field contains the process name (e.g., the executable) of the client application.  This could help identify the actual process.  It is not guaranteed, though.  The application itself can change that value through mechanisms such as [sp_SetApplicationID](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/index.html?master_sp_setapplicationid.htm).